# Chatting with Empathy

Tags: empathy, irc

I'd like to chat in some irc-channels hostet at freenode and i don't really know how. How do I create an account, how do I use it with Empathy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need an account to chat on Freenode. Just add an IRC "account" on Empathy and enter a nick. To join a channel, go to Join Room.

Answer (score 11):

On 12.10 it seems like you need to install [account-plugin-irc [image: Install account-plugin-irc]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/account-plugin-irc) package to use IRC in Empathy. Perhaps this will solve the problem on earlier versions of Ubuntu (such as 12.04) as well.

Comment: Had to do the same on 14.04. Thanks!